# Unsetting element in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove a key/value pair from an array but it does not seem to work.  Basically, I make an API call which returns JSON.  As such I do

```
$tempArray = json_decode($projects, true);
```

If I output $tempArray I see something like this

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:9 [
    "id" => 4
    "name" => "Some Project Name"
    "value" => "234"
    "user_id" => "1"
    "client_id" => "97"
    "contact" => "Jane Berry"
  ]
  1 => array:9 [
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Another Project Name"
    "value" => "6"
    "user_id" => "1"
    "client_id" => "97"
    "contact" => "John Doe"
  ]
]
```

I essentially need to remove the value element so I do this

```
unset($tempArray['value']);
```

If I output $tempArray after the unset, it displays exactly the same as before, with the value element and value there.

What do I need to do to completely remove this from my array?

Thanks

Comment: There is no key called 'value' on the first level of your array. You would need to do something like `unset($tempArray[0]['value']);` Otherwise loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unset` will not look recursivly to sub-array to remove the key `value`. Only if you have at first level a key named `value` will be removed. In your array first level keys are: 0 and 1.
So to remove `value` from all sub-arrays you have to go throw all items from the array and `unset` it. You can do this with a simple `foreach`.

```
foreach($tempArray as $key => $data) { 
   unset($data['value']);
   $tempArray[$key] = $data; //Overwrite old data with new with value unset.
}
```

Now you will not have `value` key in sub-array items.

Answer (score 1):

As per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019256/unsetting-element-in-array#comment65389012_39019256), you have no key called 'value' which is a top level key in your array. If you array looked like this:

```
$myArray = array(
    "value" => "My Value to delete",
    "anotherKey" => "hello world",
);
```

Then you could do `unset($myArray['value']);` and you would remove the key and value. In your case, the key you are looking for is nested under a numeric key `[0]` or `[1]`. You could reference these specifically like this:

```
unset($tempArray[0]['value']);
```

but what I imagine you are looking to achieve is to remove any trace of the key `value` from your array in which case you would be better off doing something like this:

```
foreach($tempArray as &$nestedArray){
    unset($nestedArray['value']);
}
```

Note the `&` symbol before the `$nestedArray`. This means 'pass by value' and will actually update the `$tempArray` in a single line without the need for anything else.

---

#### Further Reading:

- [PHP Docs - Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [PHP Docs - Foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [PHP Docs - Pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)